# Ampersand encoding in URL

Tags: asp.net, url, url-encoding

I have this code in my codebehind...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RegisterCssFile("http://example.com/default.aspx?type=fm&theme=fm");
}

private void RegisterCssFile(string path)
{
  var css = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
  css.Attributes.Add("href", path);
  css.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
  css.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
  Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
}
```

This renders

```
<link href="http://example.com/default.aspx?type=fm&amp;theme=fm" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

... which, as you can see, is wrong.

Why is the ampersand (&) encoded and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is correct.  Why do you think it's wrong?  It should be sent by the browser as just `&` after HTML un-escaping.  Does something not work for you?

Comment: It seems to destroy the query string. When I browse the generated url, I get an error. I don't get the error when the ampersand isn't encoded.

Comment: @Bridget: If you put that URL directly into your browser's address bar, then yes, it won't work.  But when the link is found within the HTML, the browser should correctly un-escape it and send only the `&`.  Why don't you try putting the URL in an `<a href` link and click on it.  Does it work then, even when escaped as shown?